# Does the following sequence defined recursively converge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I have a sequence of real numbers defined as follows. Let $n > c > 1$ be integers. We define
$$
a_{i+1} = n - \frac{c}{2 a_i - c}
$$
with $a_0 = n$. If the limit does not exist I am interested in finding minimal, or something close, value of $a_i$. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RSolve%5B%7Ba%5Bi+%2B+1%5D+%3D%3D+n+-+c%2F%282+a%5Bi%5D+-+c%29%2C+a%5B0%5D+%3D%3D+n%7D%2C+a%5Bi%5D%2C+i%5D

Answer (score 0):

The sequence can be taken for example as:

$$a_1 = \frac{n^2 - c}{n-c} > n $$

since:

$$n^2 - c > n(n-c) = n^2 - nc$$

and for $k = a_i$, we can simply have:

$$ a_{i+1} = \left( \frac{(n-c)k-c}{k-c}\right)$$

as $i \to \infty$ .

Comment: if $a_0=n$, then $a_n<n$

Comment: Yes, I have edited.